# Is there any way to refresh/update toplevel window in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm creating check button on toplevel window these check button are applied on all file stored inside cache folder but when there is addition or deletion of file in cache folder the check button didn't update is there is any way to refresh or update toplevel window without closing it.
'''

```
class encrypt_files:
            def __init__(self):
                pass
            def encrypt_file(self):
                paths =  filedialog.askopenfilenames()
                for item in paths:
                    # encryption/decryption buffer size - 64K
                    bufferSize = 64 * 1024
                    password = "FootWork"
                    # adding encrypted files to cache folder
                    pyAesCrypt.encryptFile(item,path.basename(item) + ".aes", password, bufferSize)
        class encrypt_folder:
            def __init__(self):
                pass
            def open_folder(self):
       #creating top level window
                top_level = tk.Toplevel()
                top_level.geometry("700x500+500+200")
                top_level.title("Encyption Files")
                p2 = encrypt_files()

        
                tool_bar = ttk.LabelFrame(top_level)
                tool_bar.pack(side = "top",fill = "both")
                
                main_body = ttk.LabelFrame(top_level)
                main_body.pack(side = "top",fill = "both")
                
                upload_button = ttk.Button(tool_bar,text = "Upload file",command = lambda :p2.encrypt_file())
                upload_button.grid(row = 0,column = 0)
        
        #checking for files in cache folder
                if "cache" not in os.getcwd().split(r"\ ".replace(" ", "")):
                    os.chdir(os.getcwd() + r"\cache")
                dirlist  = os.listdir()
                radiolist = {}

        #placing all check buttons on toplevel window which i want to update
                for i in dirlist:
                    radiolist[i] = tk.IntVar()
                    check_button = ttk.Checkbutton(main_body,text = i,variable = radiolist[i])
                    check_button.grid(sticky="w")
        
                top_level.mainloop()
```

'''

Comment: Are you looking for `<tkinter.Toplevel>.update()`?

Comment: @TheLizzard update doesn't work for me i tried in another function by passing toplevel as argument and also tried near toplevel mainloop()

Comment: Can you update your question showing the important bits of your code so that I can debug it?

Comment: By update you mean to refresh the changed data right. Show us an example so we can work on something.

Comment: i have edited my code in my question thank you for reviewing my question

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing built-in to do that. You'll have to write a function that iterates over the files and/or the checkbuttons and update them appropriately. Tkinter gives you all the tools you need to add or remove checkbuttons, to change their state, and to change their labels.

All of that can be done without closing the window.